# Adding a string parameter to an object

Tags: java

This is what I need to do. I'm not really sure how though.
`addGrade()` method: Accepts a String parameter representing a new grade (including category prefix) to add to the GradeBook object; and returns true if added or false if not added (e.g., if category was not in the category array).

```
private String[] categories;

public Gradebook(String[] categoriesIn) {
    categories = categoriesIn;
}

public boolean addGrade(String newGrade) {
    categories[] =  new Gradebook(newGrade);
}
```

I tried that above for starters but that's not correct

Comment: Need better explanation .

Comment: a lot more to do. you will need to use `String#spilt()` I guess

Answer (score 0):

you cannot instantiate Gradebook Class in to variable categories, because variable categories is Array of String
try to instance new array, then assign to variable categories